# TINYMCE Editor External Templates: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: javascript, tinymce, editor, tinymce-4

I am using TINYMCE Editor Version 4.8.2 (2018-08-09) and trying to add few prebuilt templates in `.html` in the list. I installed the template plugin in the plugin directory and initiated it in `init-tinymce.js` as below.

```
tinymce.init({
/* replace textarea having class .tinymce with tinymce editor */
selector: "textarea",   

/* plugin */
plugins: [
    "template"
],

/* toolbar */
toolbar: "template",

/* templates */
templates: [
    {
      title : "Default Template 1",
      src : "tinymce-templates/template1.html",
      description : "Default Template"
    },
    {
        title : "Default Template 2",
        src : "tinymce-templates/template2.html",
        description : "Default Template"
    }
]
```

});

Now when I try to open and insert my added templates then I am able to see my both template in the dropdown list but when I cant see the preview. On inspecting, I found this error shared below.

[image]

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined           plugin.min.js:1 
    at S (plugin.min.js:1)
    at i.onselect (plugin.min.js:1)
    at Vg.c.fire (tinymce.min.js:2)
    at i.fire (theme.min.js:1)
    at w (plugin.min.js:1)
    at plugin.min.js:1
    at i.<anonymous> (plugin.min.js:1)
    at Vg.c.fire (tinymce.min.js:2)
    at i.fire (theme.min.js:1)
    at HTMLDivElement.o (theme.min.js:1)
S   @   plugin.min.js:1
onselect    @   plugin.min.js:1
Vg.c.fire   @   tinymce.min.js:2
fire    @   theme.min.js:1
w   @   plugin.min.js:1
(anonymous) @   plugin.min.js:1
(anonymous) @   plugin.min.js:1
Vg.c.fire   @   tinymce.min.js:2
fire    @   theme.min.js:1
o   @   theme.min.js:1
C   @   tinymce.min.js:2
d
```

And my template is like something below...

```
<div class="mceTmpl">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="box">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <hr>
        <h2 class="intro-text text-center">Build a website
          <strong>worth visiting</strong>
        </h2>
        <hr>
        <hr class="visible-xs">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc placerat diam quis nisl vestibulum dignissim. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe where you have a `src` attribute the correct attribute is `url`.  Per the documentation I see this:

> This option lets you specify a predefined list of templates to be
>   inserted by the user into the editable area. It is structured as an
>   array with each item having a title, description and **content/url**.